# bash alias using pipline fails to run

Tags: bash

I want to sent test.tjs to pipline,

first convert to js file, then run in node

So, I tried in .bashrc file:

```
 alias tame="tamejs -o $1.js $1; node $1.js"

 alias tame="tamejs -o $1.js $1 && node $1.js"
```

They don't run properly.

Comment: Have you reloaded bash?

Comment: Yeah. source ~/.bashrc

Comment: What's a pipline?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see Shell Functions).

Try:

```
tame () { tamejs -o "$1.js" "$1" && node "$1.js"; }
```

If you want .js files instead of .tjs.js files:

```
tame () { local js=$(dirname "$1")/$(basename "$1" .tjs).js; tamejs -o "$js" "$1" && node "$js"; }
```